# How do I only set today's date or a future date with Android's DatePicker widget?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-calendar, android-datepicker

I am loading a `DatePicker` in a `DialogFragment`. I want the user to only be able to select today's date or a future date.  Various ways to use `setMinDate()` either show incorrect output or crash the app. For example, the below does not work.

```
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Please advise.

**DatePickerFragment.java**

```
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public DatePickerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int currentday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,currentyear,currentmonth,currentday);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
    dialog.setTitle("Pick a Due Date");

    return dialog;
    }


    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    EditText txtDate = (EditText) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.FEditText);
    String date=(month+1) + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    txtDate.setText(date);
    }

    ...
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get on your app crashes? And what API are you targeting? This way only works os API 11+.

Comment: targeting 11+.  

When using the setMinDate code listed above the DatePicker shows the month of October 1964.  Previous posts suggests the DatePicker has a bug and is actually showing a date in the Year 2100, but formatted badly.

Other uses of setMinDate crash the app, for example when I tried to use getTime() method.

Comment: Post the log when the app crashes.